# Exporting JPG image from LaTeX SRC-block with :async header

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-babel, preview-latex, async

I like to generate JPG images from my LaTeX/tikz drawings in my org files. For this, I use constructs like

```
#+NAME: my image
#+HEADER: :file my-image.jpg
#+BEGIN_SRC latex :results file raw :imagemagick t :iminoptions -trim -density 600
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[] (0,0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
#+END_SRC
```

This works fine, but the evaluation takes some time and I like to do it asynchronously. Therefore, I tried adding `:async` with [ob-async](https://github.com/astahlman/ob-async) to my SRC block header. But then, I get an JPG image of my typed tikz code instead of the drawing. Why is that and how can I export my images asynchronously?